# Putting an Anonymous collection into a Class

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a link query which returns different lists of data to fill different Grids on webpages,
but it always returns some standard properties as well as a collection of anonymous objects.

so I want a class which has 3 int properties for 'Total', 'Page', and 'Count'
then a property which is a collection.  I still want the property to change so I can use this object to return multiple types of queries.  I know I could 'hard-type' every query but there are so many variations of queries that it would be best to have a generic type of class which would accept an Anonymous collection.

I have tried using a property of

```
List<object> myQueryCollection
```

but get the error:

> Error 205 Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<object>`

How can I get a class which has 3 int properties and a Collection property which accepts a anonymous type.

I want to pass a proper object from my biz layer to my views...

```
var jsonData = new {
      total = totalPages,
      page = gridSettings.PageIndex,
      records = counter,
      rows = (from c in ucs select new {id = c.id, createDate =         
        c.CreateDate}).ToList()
};
```

Comment: You should edit your question instead, comments are not for writing additional code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it would be best to have a generic type of class which would accept an Anonymous collection

Then you should make your type generic, similar to what lazyberezovsky suggested in his answer. You need to take advantage of type inference, which doesn't work on constructors. But you can use a `static` factory method:

```
public static class ResultFactory
{
    public static Result<T> Create<T>(int total, int page, List<T> items)
    {
        return new Result<T> { Total = total, Page = page, Items = items };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var data = ResultFactory.Create(
      totalPages,
      gridSettings.PageIndex,
      (from c in ucs select new { c.id, createDate = c.CreateDate }).ToList());
```

If you don't want to do that, you could use a covariant interface like `IEnumerable` (or `IReadOnlyList` if you're on .Net 4.5) instead of `List`. You can't cast `List<AnonymousType>` to `List<object>` (or `IList<object>`), because that wouldn't be safe. But it's safe to cast it to `IEnumerable<object>`.

One more option would be to create `List<object>` containing objects of the anonymous type in the first place. To do that, specify the type when calling `ToList`: `.ToList<object>()` instead of `.ToList()`.

Comment: Create<T> "Cannot declare instance members in a static class'

Comment: @magister Sorry, the method was meant to be `static`, fixed now.

Answer (score 4):

You can create generic class

```
public class Result<T>
{
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int Count { get { return Items.Count; } }
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And extension method to create instance of this class parametrized with your anonymous type:

```
public static Result<T> ToResult<T>(this List<T> source)
{
    return new Result<T> { Items = source };
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = yourList.ToResult();
```

Comment: is the static method in another file... I am getting an error "Expecting class, delegate, enum, interface or struct

Comment: @magister You can't have a method directly in a file, you should put it into a `class`. And in the case of extension method, that `class` has to be `static`.

Comment: but is the static method part of the Result Class or is it separate?

Comment: @magister Like I said, it has to be in a `static class`, which means it has to be separate.

Comment: I put the static method in a separate file.  when I try to load up the new class it wants T defined....becs.Result jsonData = new becs.Result {

Comment: total = totalPages,
                    page = gridSettings.PageIndex,

Comment: Got them in separate files still says "Expecting class, delegate, enum, interface or struct

Comment: @magister [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) should be static and they should be declared on static class. Also make sure your extension method is generic (i.e. with `<T>`)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers that suggest a generic type can definitely make sense, but since you are passing this data to another class that must be reflecting into the class anyways you could use a list of objects.

The do this you need to cast the anonymous instances as part of your query, like so:

```
var jsonData = new {
      total = totalPages,
      page = gridSettings.PageIndex,
      records = counter,
      rows = (from c in ucs select new {id = c.id, createDate =         
        c.CreateDate}).Cast<Object>().ToList()
};
```

`jsonData.rows` will now be a list of objects, instead of the anonymous type.

Comment: In my answer, I have suggested a shorter way to do the same thing: `.ToList<object>()`.